# Elegant way to try/except a series of BeautifulSoup commands?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing webpages on a site displaying item data.  These items have about 20 fields which may or may not occur -- say: price, quantity, last purchased, high, low, etc.

I'm currently using a series of commands; about 20 lines of `soup.find('div',{'class':SOME_FIELD_OF_INTEREST})` to look for each separate field of interest.  (Some are in `div`, `span`, `dd`, and so on, so it's difficult to just do a `soup.find_all('div')` command.)

My question: Is there an elegant way to `try` and `except` everything such that the viewing of said code can be more compact or concise?  Right now a sample line would look like:

```
try:
    soup.find('div', {'id':'item-pic'}).img["src"]
except:
    ""
```

I was hoping to combine everything in one line.  I don't think I can syntactically run try: `<line of code> except: <code>`, and I'm not sure how I'd write a function that goes `try_command(soup.find('div',{'id':'item-pic'}).img["src"])` without actually running the command.

I'd love to hear if anybody has any advice (including: "this isn't possible/practical, move on"). :)

EDIT: After talking a bit, I guess I wanted to see what is good practice for inline exception handling, and if that's the right route to take.

Comment: I you are searching portions in a text, that's a job for regexes.

Comment: Do you want to run an equivalent of XPATH expression: `//div[@id="item-pic"]/img/@src` using BeautifulSoup? Please, provide more examples. Have you read [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree)? `try/except` seems like a bad idea here.

Comment: Off the top of my head I vaguely remember incompatibilities between XPATH and BeautifulSoup... lemme try it right now...

Comment: So the command currently breaks because of the `.args` that follow the `soup.find()` command.  After some more thought I suppose I could nest `.find` commands instead to make sure there's no breakage.

Comment: This is a really great question. I'm in this exact situation now. The answers below aren't really sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like that:

```
def try_these(start_obj, *args) :
        obj = start_obj
        for trythat in args :
            if obj is None :
                return None
            try :
                if isinstance(trythat, str) :
                    obj = getattr(obj, trythat)
                else :
                    method, opts = trythat
                    obj = getattr(obj, method)(*opts)
            except :
                return None
        return obj    
src = try_these(soup, ('find', ({'id':'item-pic'},),), 
                      'img', 
                      ('get', ('src',),) )
```

where you can pass `str` to get attribute from object or `tuple` (str method, tuple params), finally you'll get `None` or result. I'm not familiar with soup so I'm not sure if `get('src')` would be a good approach (as probably its not a dict), anyway you can easily modify that snippet to accept something more than only 'call or attr'.

---

Inspired by your question I wrote simple python module that helps to deal with such situation, you can find it [here](https://github.com/lupatus/silentcrawler)

```
import silentcrawler    

wrapped = silentcrawler.wrap(soup)
# just return None on failure
print wrapped.find('div', {'id':'item-pic'}).img["src"].value_

# or
def on_success(value) :
    print 'found value:', value
wrapped = silentcrawler.wrap(soup, success=on_success)
# call on_success if everything will be ok
wrapped.find('div', {'id':'item-pic'}).img["src"].value_
```

there is more possibilities

Comment: +1 for silentwrapper, although it's a shame it uses a callback instead of returning a wrapper object. The `try_these` function seems more complex and less elegant than a simple series of try/excepts..

Comment: I don't get why it is a shame, anyway you have couple ways of using it. Callback was useful for me (there is success and failure callback), but you can get wrapper object, wrapped object, you can set default value and whatever you want, see short documentation attached to module: https://github.com/lupatus/silentcrawler

Comment: Oh, stupid me. I didn't read the example code properly, and missed that the first method returns the object (or `None`). The callback seemed like it would be strange in this specific case, but returning the value looks perfect \o/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to find some fields based on an interesting class name, but they are not necessary the same element (not all `<div>`)

If so, with BeautifulSoup you can pass a compiled regex (from [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) in place of a string in many cases. For example:

```
print soup.findAll(re.compile(".*"), {'class': 'blah'})
# [<div class="blah"></div>, <span class="blah"></span>]
```

We can use this to tidily loop over all the relevant looking DOM elements which might contain the image:

```
import re
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS


html = """
<html>
<body>
<div class="blah"></div>
<span class="blah"><img src="yay.jpg"></span>
<span class="other"></div>

</body>
</html>
"""

def get_img_src(soup, cssclass):
    for item in soup.findAll(re.compile(".*"), {'class': cssclass}):
        if item.img is not None and 'src' in dict(item.img.attrs):
            return item.img['src']


soup = BS(html)
img = get_img_src(soup, cssclass = "blah")
print img # outputs yay.jpg, or would return None if nothing was found
```

Debatable, but I think using the `if` checks is more appropriate in this case, because `item.img['src']`

It could equally be written like this:

```
def get_img_src(soup, cssclass):
    for item in soup.findAll(re.compile(".*"), {'class': cssclass}):
        try:
            return item.img['src']
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

..but it's strange to catch `TypeError` here (as `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` isn't really the exception you are trying to catch, it's a byproduct of the syntax used by BeautifulSoup to access attributes)

Comment: That was nifty -- I keep forgetting to regex things so I DR(M).  Thanks for the tip!

Though my main problem is exception handling and if I can make it stylistically cleaner...

Comment: @binarysolo Oh, I was thinking the regex could be used to elegantly get the result you are after.. but completely forgot to write that bit of the answer! Edited