# Is this the correct way to use try except for Beauitfulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some elements from eBay. Lots of the listings do not have the same format. I made a try-except block but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. What I'm trying to achieve is if total_sold_price cannot find the first element (len == 0), then try a different approach.

```
try:
    if len(soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text) > 0:
        total_sold_price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text
    else:
        total_sold_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mm-saleDscPrc"]').text 
except:
    total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup = ""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to try/except a series of BeautifulSoup commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783933/elegant-way-to-try-except-a-series-of-beautifulsoup-commands)

Comment: First of all, you should never user a bare `except:` block. A block like that can capture exceptions totally unrelated to the code in the `try:` block, like `SystemError`